# Getting selected value from ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

On button click I want to get a value from a `ListView` column. I have tried using `DataRow` but I am getting `NullReferenceExpection`.

```
int row = listView.SelectedIndex;
DataRow dr = listView.Items.GetItemAt(row) as DataRow;
long ID = Convert.ToInt64(dr["ID"]);
TextBoxID.Text = ID.ToString();
```

Comment: Try `ListViewItem` instead of `DataRow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView.GetItemAt()` returns a `ListViewItem`.  If you try to cast that to a `DataRow` via `as`, you'll get a null because that's what `as` returns when you try to cast to the wrong type.  Use `ListViewItem` where you've used `DataRow`, and use the `SubItems` list to get field values.  Also note that `GetItemAt()` returns null if there's no item at the specified index.

Answer (score 1):

I read the answer above but it was ambiguous so now I am giving the full code to do the job.

```
        int index = list_View.SelectedIndex;
        DataRowView CompRow;
        long KOT;
        CompRow = list_View.Items.GetItemAt(index) as DataRowView;
        KOT = Convert.ToInt16(CompRow["KOT"]);
        MessageBox.Show(KOT.ToString());
```